# Deploying a specific version of a software from a juju charm?

Tags: juju, postgresql

Suppose I'm using the postgresql charm to deploy my databases. How can I control the version of the PostgreSQL (9.1, 9.2, 9.3, etc) that is deployed?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PostgreSQL charm has a configuration option for `version`

http://manage.jujucharms.com/charms/precise/postgresql

Assuming your PostgreSQL service is called `postgresql` you would run the following command after it's deployed.

`juju set postgresql version=1.0`

Pre-deployment you can also pass a yaml configuration file. See `juju help deploy` for more information.